# Python: why does it say it takes at least 2 arguments (1 given) when I clearly gave it two?

Tags: python

```
img = ImageLib()
init = img.grayscale(file='something.jpg')
img.diff(init=init, file='another.jpg')
```

it gives error saying :

```
TypeError: diff() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

but I gave it two arguments!!!!! why is this happening?

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you have something wrong with the function signature.  While you gave it 2 arguments, the traceback really means that the function takes 2 *positional*<sup>1</sup> arguments.  Perhaps one of your keyword arguments doesn't match with the names of the positional arguments:

```
>>> def foo(a, b, c='foo'):
...     pass
... 
>>> foo(a="cat", b="bar")
>>> foo(1, c="bar")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: foo() takes at least 2 arguments (2 given)
```

<sup><sup>1</sup>Technically, it's just 2 *required* arguments.  In python3, you can have required keyword (i.e. non-positional) arguments.  See comments.</sup>

Comment: Your answer may be good for python2, but in python3 keyword arguments *can* be mandatory: `foo(a,b,*,c)`. The error message means exactly what's written:  `foo()` takes at least `N` (mandatory) arguments. (*Of these arguments*) `K` (were) given.

Comment: @Bakuriu -- Fair enough, but python 3 (at least 3.4 on my machine) gives more helpful error messages:  `TypeError: foo() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'c'` which isn't what OP was getting.